# SSIS Not building file path when executed via Agent Job but works in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm just after some advice\thoughts.

I have a SSIS Package (SQL Server 2016) that performs the following:

- It loops through a folder on a network share (I have even granted the 'Everyone' group full control to this folder and assigns the file paths on files in the folder to a variable (@FilePaths)
- This variable is then used as an attachment in a Send Email task
- When I execute interactively in Visual Studio\SSDT it works fine - I receive an email with the attachment(s)
- If I call via a SQL Agent Job I receive the email, but no attachment
- As a test, I have also inserted the @FilePaths as the body of the email - again when executed via SSDT I receive the path of the files in the email and when via the Agent Job the body is blank
- I'm using a script task within a loop to retrieve the file names

In summary, when executed via the SQL Agent job, it cannot 'see' the files to retrieve the paths, even though I have set the Everyone group to the folder and also the account the Agent is being run as.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be missing here?  It has to be permissions of some sort.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the Agent can't access the share. I *assume* you're using a full UNC path and that the SQL Server agent is running as an AD Account? SSISDB has an abundance of logs when a package is executed; what do those say?

Comment: I'm using '\\servername\folder\folder' as the path.  The logs say it executed fine, which I suppose it did, it just didn't write the paths to the @FilePaths variable

Comment: So you can see all files in the logs? That doesn't line up with your description; if you can see that `@FilePaths` is being assigned a value in the logs, then the email will contain that value (if you are using it's value). if that is the case, that means something is wrong with your package (or perhaps you've deployed an old version, or not redeployed). Also, what about the question i asked about the Agent Service Account?

Comment: I have set the logs to verbose and am re-running. The Agent is running as an AD Account and I can confirm this account also has full control on the Share

Comment: Just be aware there are two levels of permissions: Share (which is often set to everyone to save hassles) but then there is also the actual permissions on the folder itself. Regardless, it would usually throw an error if this was the case. Can you clarify whether your SSDT tests are on the SQL Server or not? It could possibly be an email server issue not allowing attachments through. Try hard coding a path and see if that works. Try hard coding a local path (local to the SQL Server)

Comment: thanks for the tip @Nick.McDermaid I will try this....

Comment: I suspect, once you look at the logs, you'll see something like `Foreach Loop Container:Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.`

Comment: even though I put the logging in verbose it still doesn't tell me what (or if) it assigned a value to @FilePaths.  I'm using a script task within a loop to retrieve the file names.

Comment: Why not use a For Each Loop container?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If I hard code a file from the folder share and execute a Package with a simple Send Email Task via an agent job, it works!

Comment: @Larnu yes my bad, I am using Script Task within a For Each Loop Container, sorry if I wasn't clearer.

Comment: So why does it not work when using a Variable but does when hard coded?

Comment: I think I may have solved it. I have changed the TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2016 and re-deployed to the catalog.  If I call the email package from an Agent job it works and attaches the email.  I won't be 100% happy though until the overnight job has run which this forms part of.  But it is looking to work on the surface.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Michael, I would encourage you to post your solution comment as an answer and accept it. It would be helpful for future users who come across this question.

Comment: @digital.aaron will do - I will see if it runs 100% tomorrow as this is part of a large overnight SSIS Package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to finish this - the overnight job was successful - so the fix was to change the 'TargetServerVersion' from 2017 to 2016 and re-deploy to the SSIS catalog.

Comment: legend, isnt ssis i heap of poo